# rsyslog loses messages from firewall

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, syslog

I am trying to make `rsyslog` to log messages from `iptables` `MASQUERADE`. I have `iptables` `LOG` rule in `nat` table and `PREROUTING` chain before the MASQUERADE rules.

The actual `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 ! -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j LOG --log-prefix "FireWallFW: "
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 ! -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

When I send 100 new packages through the MASQUERADE, iptables counters indicate the 100 packages were matched by both the MASQUERADE as well as by the LOG rules. Unfortunately `rsyslog` puts in logfile a dozen or at most about 30 messages losing information about real count of masqueraded packages. It does not matter if I have sync enabled or disabled on the logfile or if `RepeatedMsgReduction` is on or of.

What is going on here? Is `rsyslog` to slow or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Have you tried adding `$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0` to `rsyslog.conf` and restarting rsyslog [as suggested here](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Are+you+losing+system+logging+information+%28and+don%27t+know+it%29%3F/15106)?

Comment: Yes. It does not help.

Comment: Not sure. You could try another logger like metalog. Please include your iptables rules in your question so we have it for reference.

Comment: Before trying something else I wanted to check out default logger installed by debian. Probably it was a mistake... I added to iptables rules to the question.

Comment: Confirmed: syslog-ng has virtually *no* problems with logging *every single* packet that hit the iptables LOG target.